# How do I find which Office 365 version I have?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I want to know if it is **Office 365 personal** or **Office 365 student** or **Office 365 ProPlus** or something else because I want to have PowerPivot tab in Excel and I have read that it is only available in select few versions of Office 365.I have viewed the product information after opening Excel --> Account --> Product Information. [image: 1]]

Comment: I can navigate to the Office 365 `My Account` page, sign in with the Microsoft account that is associated with this install of Office, and it shows that I am utilizing `Office 365 Home`:  https://stores.office.com/myaccount/home.aspx

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to know if it is Office 365 personal/studentProPlus or something else

Use the following instructions to find the details of your Office subscription:

> Office 365 subscription uses the File tab and the Office Backstage
>   view, what you see after you click File. Here's what you see in Word
>   after choosing File > Account.
>
> [image: File > Account in an Office 365 subscription]
>
> [image: Number one in a pink circle] Shows if you have a
>   subscription Office product and what Office product it is.
>
> [image: Number two in a pink circle.] Shows you the full version
>   number.
>
> [image] After you click About Word,
>   you’ll see what bit you are running—32-bit or 64-bit.

Source [Find details for other versions of Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-details-for-other-versions-of-Office-8e83dd74-3b83-4528-bda6-6ff6118f8293)